# Can I get rid of `.000Z` when using `Date.prototype.toISOString`?

Tags: javascript, date

I've got some data represented as an object of class X. Some fields of that object contain dates - instances of the standard built-in `Date` constructor.

The thing is that I need to pass that object of class X as a JSON string using Axios. And when the fields representing dates are converted to strings, the `Date.prototype.toISOString` is used on them. However, it converts the strings to the following format: `2017-11-14T06:22:43.000Z`, - while I need them to be *almost* the same, but without this `.000Z` at the end (the server seems to dislike that).

I see 2 options how can I achieve that:

1. Modify the object manually
   Though it doesn't sound that bad, it has some drawbacks: first of all, there is actually not a single object of class X I have, but a lot of them. Possibly, hundrends. So it might become a pretty expensive operation in terms of performance. The second thing is that I'm pretty much sure that there *should* be a more elegant solution.
2. Augment the `Date.prototype.toISOString` method
   I've tried to do so, but don't know if it's a good decision (1) and I don't know how can I make it (2) the way that the method first calls itself (to perform what it has to) and then I modify its output with `substr`: there occurs an endless recursion. Look:

```js
Date.prototype.toISOString = function(...args) {
  const res = Date.prototype.toISOString(...args);
  return res.substr(0, 19);
};

const date = new Date();
document.write(date.toISOString());
```

The following way it doesn't work as well:

```js
const originalMethod = Date.prototype.toISOString;

Date.prototype.toISOString = function(...args) {
  const res = originalMethod(...args);
  return res.substr(0, 19);
};

const date = new Date();
document.write(date.toISOString());
```

```html
See the console. It outputs "Method Date.prototype.toISOString called on incompatible receiver undefined"
```

So, why doesn't that work? And, more importantly, what would be the best way of solving my problem?

Comment: This is a weird problem, because an ISO date/time string is *supposed* to look like that. The Z at the end, and the 3 zeros, are the millisecond and time zone indicator.

Comment: @Pointy I agree with you and with the ISO commetee, but the backend doesn't agree with us both.

Comment: "*So, why doesn't that work?*" because you lose the value of `this` with your call. "*what would be the best way of solving my problem?*" by ***not*** overwriting methods in built-in objects that most likely will lead to other code misbehaving as well. Just write your own function that takes a date and returns the format you want.

Comment: @VLAZ *"because you lose the value of `this` with your call"* - doesn't look like the case for me. Where do I lose it exactly? *"most likely will lead to other code misbehaving as well"* - or rather behaving properrly (in my case, or at least for my specific application). *"Just write your own function that takes a date and returns the format you want"* - but how do I make the `JSON.stringify` use *my* function when converting dates?

Comment: "*Where do I lose it exactly?*" You call `originalMethod(...args);` but don't have a `this`, so when the method is called, `this = undefined`. Which is the error you get - calling `toISOString()` on `undefined`. "*but how do I make the JSON.stringify use my function when converting dates?*" supply your own serialisation logic. You could also make your own `class MyDate extends Date` and change the `toJSON()` but it's probably too much of a hassle than just changing the `JSON.stringify` calls.

Comment: Did you check what is your server accepted format, where did you store in server, like mysql, sqlserver etc.. if you knkw that where and which format then you can cast this datetime string

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ I'm not working with the backend at all. I've already asked me backend-responsible-colleague that maybe the server would also accept the correct ISO format or that maybe it's a typo in API docs, but haven't heard from him bavk yet.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to trim the "Z" as it represents UTC and means a zero offset. Without the Z, the offset for the date and time is unknown, so treated as local by parsers conforming to ISO 8601 or ECMA-262, and hence represents a different moment in time in for each host with a different offset for that local date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why doesn't that work?

Because you're calling the `originalMethod` without a `this` value. A working code would be

```
const originalMethod = Date.prototype.toISOString;

Date.prototype.toISOString = function(...args) {
  const res = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
  return res.substr(0, 19);
};
```

> I don't know if it's a good decision

No, definitely not. Do not mess with builtins - other parts of your code (or its dependencies) might rely on their correct functioning.

> What would be the best way of solving my problem?

Don't modify the `toJSON` behaviour of all `Date` instances, modify the serialisation of your `X` objects only:

```
class X {
  …
  toJSON() {
    return {
      ...this,
      // TODO: fix backend to acccept standard timestamp formats
      date: this.date.toISOString().replace(/(?:\.\d{1,3})?Z$/, ''),
      …
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: And use it as something like `JSON.stringify(xInstance.toJson())`?

Comment: @smellyshovel No, [`JSON.stringify` does that for you automatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior). You can use just `JSON.stringify(xInstance)`. It works also on anything that contains `X` instances. Notice that this is in fact the same mechanism that [`Date` is using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON), which allowed you to affect serialisation by overwriting `toISOString()` in the first place.

Comment: `this.date.toISOString().slice(0, -4)` -> `this.date.toISOString().slice(0, -5)` though :) Works like a charm. Exactly the solution I was looking for! Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) to be used with `JSON.stringify()`. You can add special handling for any dates but leave any other value intact:

```js
function customReplacer(key, value) {
  if (key === "") //initial object
    return value;
  
  if (this[key] instanceof Date) //any date
    return value.slice(0, 19);
  
  return value; //anything else
}

const obj = {
  a: "hello world",
  b: {
    c: 42
  },
  d: [1, 2, 3],
  e: new Date(),
  f: {
    g: true,
    h: new Date(),
    i: null
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, customReplacer, 4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that `value` is going to be the *serialised value*, not a Date object. Hence, to get the initial non-serialised object, you need to get `this[key]` - the function is going to be called with the object that's currently serialised as `this`.

Comment: I din't know about that second `customReplacer`-param that the `stringify` method can take! Might be very useful! The thing is that Axios calls `JSON.stringify` for me, and I can't (at least AFAIK) pass the replacer somehow to Axios for it to use it when converting my objects to JSON. Anyway, thanks for your time. This should be better than modifying the existing built-ins anyway.

Comment: @smellyshovel `axios` has [a request config option `transformRequest`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) which allows you to apply customisation(s) to the payload before sending. You can pass that configuration and apply serialisation there.